# Only python file can read a specific file

Tags: python, django, linux, openssl, chmod

For a High school projet, I have to use a private key to encrypt file. I changed permission to my pk, only the root user can read this file. I change the owner (to root) and put the uid right to this python file, but when I execute this python file, I can't have access to my pk, for me I have to change the right of python, but I didn't want, (problem of security).
Do you have any idea to have access to a file only by a python file?

The python file is included on a django project (view.py), I had too the idea to use the pid of the process but it didn't change my problem.

I used chown root and chmod with 0777 on my view.py but it said that I can't have access to read this file (has the read for owner root).

My traceback error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mora/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mora/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mora/Bureau/secProject/computer_project_54740/secuServer/accounts/views.py", line 65, in home_view
    with open("certificats/pkeyRSA.key", "r") as fd:

Exception Type: PermissionError at /home/
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'certificats/pkeyRSA.key'```


I added the uid right to python file with:
```sudo chown root view.py
sudo chmod 0777 view.py```
for the pkeyRSA.key:
```sudo chown root pkeyRSA.key
sudo chmod u+r pkeyRSA.key```
````

Comment: The access mode of the python file does not matter with respect to the `pk`. You run the Python file with a certain user, if that user has no access to a file that will be opened with the program, then that will not happen. You can change ownership of the program or access rights,but this is to *read*/*update*/*execute* the program. But the runner itself (the user that invokes the python file), will need access to the file the program is supposed to open.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is the full traceback error?

Comment: Yes I know Willem, the pk has the read access for root, and I changed the owner of my python file to root and change the permission, normally if the python file execute with the right and uid of root, it should work, but not in my case.
I added the traceback error

Comment: @LeonardoRafaelMora: but the owner of the Python file will not change *anything*, this will *not* be the owner of the *process* when you *run* the file. The python interpreter will simply try to open the Python file and run with the user of that *invoked* the interpreter. If that would use the owner of the python file, it would be a severe *privilege escalation* issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I used `chown root` and `chmod` with `0777` on my view.py but it said that I can't have access to read this file (has the read for owner root).

The owner or access permissions of the `views.py` don't matter with respect to opening (another) file. You simply run a Python program with a user (by default the one that starts the program, although you can change the user of the program). The Python files are thus not indepdent entities that run each with a different user, in fact the owner of the file does not matter *at all*, as long as the interpreter can *read* the files.

This thus means that the `python` program that runs the Django server, will eventually try to open the file, and therefore the operating system will check if the user that *runs* the program has permissions to open the file.

The fact that a `*.py` file has a certain owner or permissions itself does not matter much. It matters if the user that *runs* the Python program tries to *open* the Python file to start the program, but the program does not change ownership of the *program run* (the "*process*") in case the file has a different owner, that would be a severe [*Privilege escalation* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) issue.

You thus will have to run the Python file with the correct user, like:

```
sudo python manage.py runserver   # very bad idea
```

the idea is thus to make the file accessible to the user that you use to *run* the webserver, like `www-data` for example.

Comment: Oke so I only have to create a user to execute this project and only this user can have access to privatekey, I will try this, thanks